# How to sort a a specific column out in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to get the table below for the column O

```html
  

  BB    K   C   O   P
    1   1   c1  o1  4
    2   1   c2  o1  1
    3   1   c3  o1  8
    4   1   c4  o2  3
    5   1   c5  o2  4
    6   1   c6  o2  9
    7   2   c1  o1  2
    8   2   c2  o1  1
    9   2   c3  o1  3
    10  2   c4  o2  8
    11  2   c5  o2  7
    12  2   c6  o2  9
    13  3   c1  o1  6
    14  3   c2  o1  10
    15  3   c3  o1  6
    16  3   c4  o2  2
    17  3   c5  o2  9
    18  3   c6  o2  5
```

The codes used are :

```html
tibble(BB= c(1:18)) %>% 
    group_by(K= factor(rep(row_number(), each=6, length.out = n()))) %>% 
    mutate(C = str_c('c', row_number())) %>% 
    group_by(O= factor(rep(row_number(), each=2, length.out = n()))) %>% 
    mutate(P = sample(1:10, n(), replace = TRUE)) %>% 
ungroup
```

I struggle to sort out the column O

Comment: What is the logic to create column `O` ?

Comment: If you look at the column C, c1,c2,c3 get o1 and c4,c5 and c6 get o2 .  K has  6 values of 1 , 3 gos to  c1,c2,c3 and 3 goes goes to c4,c5 and c6.

Comment: Do you want c1, c2, c3 to go to o1 or half of the values should go to o1 and other half to o2? What if there are more c values? From c1 to c10?

Comment: Half of the values should go to o1 and the other half to o2. If we have c1 to c10, again half go to o1 and half go to o2

Comment: But then what's the logic for group_by on this column?

Comment: I just tried it, but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rep` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(K) %>%
  mutate(O = rep(c('o1', 'o2'), each = n()/2, length.out = n()))

#      BB K     C     O         P
#   <int> <fct> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1     1 1     c1    o1        8
# 2     2 1     c2    o1        6
# 3     3 1     c3    o1        2
# 4     4 1     c4    o2       10
# 5     5 1     c5    o2       10
# 6     6 1     c6    o2        9
# 7     7 2     c1    o1        9
# 8     8 2     c2    o1        3
# 9     9 2     c3    o1        2
#10    10 2     c4    o2        6
#11    11 2     c5    o2        9
#12    12 2     c6    o2        3
#13    13 3     c1    o1        8
#14    14 3     c2    o1        1
#15    15 3     c3    o1        2
#16    16 3     c4    o2        2
#17    17 3     c5    o2        7
#18    18 3     c6    o2        5
```

Answer (score 1):

user330,
Here is another way to build your tibble:

```
# Load Libraries
library('tidyverse')

# Set up Tibble
df <- tibble(BB = seq(1:18)) %>% 
  mutate(K = rep(1:3, each=6)) %>% 
  mutate(C = rep(paste0("c",seq(1:6),sep=""), times = 3)) %>% 
  mutate(O = rep(paste0("o",seq(1:2),sep=""), each = 3, times = 3)) %>% 
  mutate(P = sample(1:10, n(), replace = TRUE))

# Check results
df
#> # A tibble: 18 x 5
#>       BB     K C     O         P
#>    <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
#>  1     1     1 c1    o1       10
#>  2     2     1 c2    o1        2
#>  3     3     1 c3    o1        8
#>  4     4     1 c4    o2        8
#>  5     5     1 c5    o2       10
#>  6     6     1 c6    o2        1
#>  7     7     2 c1    o1        1
#>  8     8     2 c2    o1        9
#>  9     9     2 c3    o1        4
#> 10    10     2 c4    o2        9
#> 11    11     2 c5    o2        7
#> 12    12     2 c6    o2        3
#> 13    13     3 c1    o1        3
#> 14    14     3 c2    o1       10
#> 15    15     3 c3    o1        3
#> 16    16     3 c4    o2        7
#> 17    17     3 c5    o2        4
#> 18    18     3 c6    o2        5
```